# Relation between trilinear forms, Jacobi identity and closed $2$-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a trilinear mapping such that
\begin{equation}
f(x,y,z)=-f(x,z,y)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
f(x,y,z)+f(y,z,x)+f(z,x,y)=0
\end{equation}

From the first identity, I think $x \to f(x,\cdot,\cdot)$ becomes a $2$-form.

Next, it seems quite plausible from the second identity that the $2-$form $x \to f(x,\cdot,\cdot)$ is "closed".

However, I am quite confused about how to apply the exterior derivative to this $x \to f(x,\cdot,\cdot)$ and check its closedness..

Could anyone please clarify for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of calculating $d\omega$ for $\omega$ the form $x\mapsto f(x,\cdot,\cdot)$ becomes somewhat simpler in coordinates.

Writing $f(x,y,z)=\sum_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}x^\alpha y^\beta z^\gamma$, where each $f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ is constant, we have the folowing rules $f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}+f_{\alpha\gamma\beta}=0$ and $f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}+f_{\beta\gamma\alpha}+f_{\gamma\alpha\beta}=0$. Then $\omega=\sum_{\alpha,\beta<\gamma}\frac{1}{2}(f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}-f_{\alpha\gamma\beta})x^\alpha dx^\beta\wedge dx^\gamma$. This gives \begin{align}d\omega&=\sum_{\alpha, \beta<\gamma} \frac{1}{2}(f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}-f_{\alpha\gamma\beta})dx^\alpha\wedge dx^\beta\wedge dx^\gamma\\
&=\sum_{\alpha<\beta<\gamma}\frac{1}{2}(f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}-f_{\beta\alpha\gamma}+f_{\beta\gamma\alpha}-f_{\alpha\gamma\beta}+f_{\gamma\alpha\beta}-f_{\gamma\beta\alpha})dx^\alpha\wedge dx^\beta\wedge dx^\gamma\\
&=\sum_{\alpha<\beta<\gamma}\frac{1}{2}(f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}+f_{\beta\gamma\alpha}+f_{\gamma\alpha\beta}-f_{\alpha\gamma\beta}-f_{\beta\alpha\gamma}-f_{\gamma\beta\alpha})dx^\alpha\wedge dx^\beta\wedge dx^\gamma\\
&=\sum_{\alpha<\beta<\gamma}(f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}+f_{\beta\gamma\alpha}+f_{\gamma\alpha\beta})dx^\alpha\wedge dx^\beta\wedge dx^\gamma=0\end{align}

EDIT:
We may write that $f(x,y,z)=\sum f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}x^\alpha y^\beta z^\gamma$ because any trilinear map is determined by its value on each of the basis elements of $\mathbb{R}^n\otimes \mathbb{R}^n\otimes\mathbb{R}^n$ which are expressed as $e_\alpha\otimes e_\beta\otimes e_\gamma$

Comment: Can you briefly remind me why $f$ is necessarily a linear combination of $x_i y_j z_k$? I forgot how to verify this rigorously..

Comment: I have edited the post to fix the type error and clarify the expression for $f$.

Comment: One more suggestion: Since you have $f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}=-f_{\alpha\gamma\beta}$ to start with, just write $\omega = \sum_{\alpha,\,\beta<\gamma} f_{\alpha\beta\gamma}x^\alpha dx^\beta\wedge dx^\gamma$. That'll save half your terms.

Answer (score 5):

The relevant formula is the "conceptual" formulation of the exterior derivative. If $\omega$ is a $2$-form and $X,Y,Z$ are vector fields (here, on $\Bbb R^3$, we have
\begin{multline*}
d\omega(X,Y,Z) = X(\omega(Y,Z))+Y(\omega(Z,X))+Z(\omega(X,Y)) \\ - \omega([X,Y],Z) + \omega([X,Z],Y) - \omega([Y,Z],X).
\end{multline*}
In your case, we take $X,Y,Z$ to be the constant vector fields $e_i=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, $e_j=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$, $e_k=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ on $\Bbb R^n$, and then
$\omega(x)(e_j,e_k) = f(x,e_j,e_k)=a_{jk}(x)$. Here is the crucial point I missed at first: Since $f$ is trilinear, the functions $a_{jk}$ are linear functions of $x$, so $\frac{\partial f(x,e_j,e_k)}{\partial x_i}= f(e_i,e_j,e_k)$.
The bracket terms all vanish because the vector fields commute. So we're left with
\begin{align*}
d\omega(e_i,e_j,e_k) &= e_i(f(x,e_j,e_k)) + e_j(f(x,e_k,e_i)) + e_k(f(x,e_i,e_j)) \\ &= f(e_i,e_j,e_k) + f(e_j,e_k,e_i) + f(e_k,e_i,e_j) = 0,
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: The first answer seems to explain all?

Comment: I think the last equality is not completely correct. Since $f$ is linear we should have $e_i(f(x, e_j, e_k)) = f(e_i, e_j, e_k)$ right?

Comment: Yeah, I'm in the middle of editing. @Keith: I wanted to show the conceptual approach from the coordinate-free formula for the exterior derivative, but I hit post too early.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega$ be the $2$-form corresponding to $f$. Let $u, v, w$ be three constant vector fields. The exterior derivative of $\omega$ in Euclidean space is given by the invariant formula

\begin{equation}
(\mathrm{d}\omega)(u,v,w) = \mathcal{L}_u \omega(v, w) + \mathcal{L}_v \omega (w, u) + \mathcal{L}_w \omega(u, v).
\end{equation}

Since $\omega$ is linear (as a function of the base point), we may write
$$\mathcal{L}_u \omega(v, w) =\omega_u(v, w) - \omega_0(v, w) = f(u,v,w),$$
and similarly for the other terms. Hence $f(u,v,w) + f(v,w,u) + f(w,v,u) = 0$.

Comment: I'll return the favor. Your original formula has no $u$ on the left-hand side. You have to be more careful in defining $\omega$. This invariant formula is, amazingly, not as well-known as the one I used.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the typo. The formula is really the same as the one you have used, save for the Lie bracket terms which do not need to appear in the Euclidean case since $u,v,w$ are constant.

Comment: Yes, of course, I realize. But, to judge from most posts on MSE, most people are very uncomfortable with the Lie derivative of differential forms.